# Column Formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, json

I am trying to implement column formatting on a column that can have a value from (1-17)

**Pseudocode**
=IF(value<=4,"Low",
IF(value=5,"Low-Medium",
IF(value=6,"Low-Medium",
IF(value=7,"Low-Medium",
IF(value=8,"Medium",
IF(value=9,"Medium",
IF(value=10,"Medium",
IF(value=11,"Medium",
IF(value=12,"Medium-High",
IF(value=13,"Medium-High",
IF(value=14,"Medium-High",
IF(value=15,"Medium-High",
IF(value=16,"Medium-High",
IF(value>=17,"High"))))))))))))))

**Json**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "=if(@currentField <= 4, 'sp-field-severity--blocked', '',if(@currentField == 5, 'sp-field-severity--warning', ''))"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "span",
        "style": {
          "display": "inline-block",
          "padding": "0 4px"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "iconName": "=if(@currentField <= 70, 'Error', '')"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "span",
        "txtContent": "=if(@currentField <= 4, 'Error', if(@currentField == 5, 'hello'))"
      }
    ]
  }
```

What am doing wrong?  It just shows the json code in the display view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the JSON formatting below.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "=if(@currentField <= 4, 'sp-field-severity--low', if(@currentField<=7 ,'sp-field-severity--good',if(@currentField<=11,'sp-field-severity--warning',if(@currentField<=16,'sp-field-severity--severeWarning','sp-field-severity--blocked'))))"
    },
    "children": [     
      {
        "elmType": "span",
        "txtContent": "=if(@currentField <= 4, 'Low', if(@currentField<=7 ,'Low-Medium',if(@currentField<=11,'Medium',if(@currentField<=16,'Medium-High','High'))))"
      }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an issue with your condition statements.  The statement if([conditional], [if true do this], [if false do this]) seems to be off a bit.

```
"class": "=if(@currentField <= 4, 'sp-field-severity--blocked', '',if(@currentField == 5, 'sp-field-severity--warning', ''))"
```

In the above snippet your false statement is blank and then you have another IF statement which should be where the false statement is.

When I did this just for testing it worked...the conditions need to be tweaked a bit more but it looks to be on the right path.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "=if(@currentField <= 4, 'sp-field-severity--blocked', if(@currentField>5,'sp-field-severity--warning','sp-field-severity--low'))"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "span",
        "style": {
          "display": "inline-block",
          "padding": "0 4px"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "iconName": "=if(@currentField <= 70, 'Error', '')"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "span",
        "txtContent": "=if(@currentField <= 4, 'Error', if(@currentField>5 ,'hello','goodby'))"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I hope that helps you out.